# ServiceAccount in GKE fails authentication

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I need to create ServiceAccounts that can access a GKE cluster. Internally I do this with the following commands:

```
kubectl create serviceaccount onboarding --namespace kube-system
kubectl apply -f onboarding.clusterrole.yaml
kubectl create clusterrolebinding onboarding --clusterrole=onboarding --serviceaccount=kube-system:onboarding
```

Where the contents of the file `onboarding.clusterrole.yaml` are something like this:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: onboarding
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - '*'
  resources:
  - 'namespace,role,rolebinding,resourcequota'
  verbs:
  - '*'
```

The ServiceAccount resource is created as expected and the ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding also look right, but when I attempt to access the API using this new role, I get an Authentication failure.

```
curl -k -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer [REDACTED]" https://36.195.83.167/api/v1/namespaces
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "namespaces is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:kube-system:onboarding\" cannot list namespaces at the cluster scope: Unknown user \"system:serviceaccount:kube-system:onboarding\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "kind": "namespaces"
  },
  "code": 403
```

The response suggests an unknown user, but I confirmed the ServiceAccount exists and is in the Subjects of the ClusterRoleBinding. Is it possible to define a ServiceAccount in this way for GKE?

I am using the exact process successfully on kubernetes clusters we run in our datacenters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GKE should have the same process. Does your `kubectl` version match that of the GKE cluster? Not sure if this is the issue but the `ClusterRole` needs plurals for the resources and the resources are represented as lists:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: onboarding
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - '*'
  resources:
  - namespaces
  - roles
  - rolebindings
  - resourcequotas
  verbs:
  - '*'
```

Works for me on K8s 1.11.x:

```
curl -k -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer [REDACTED]" https://127.0.0.1:6443/api/v1/namespaces
{
  "kind": "NamespaceList",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces",
    "resourceVersion": "12345678"
  },
  ...
```

Comment: After editing my ClusterRole to have plurals and one per line (they were comma separated as seen in the gist I posted to Lukas's answer), it now works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are creating the service account, role and role binding to have API access to your kubernetes cluster, the only "hic" is that the resources are not well configured. check [this document](https://github.com/devopscube/kubenetes-rbac-resources-verbs) on how to configure rbac roles, resources-verbs, as well with their definition and examples.

Comment: That's a great resource showing examples of common RBAC combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the output of `kubectl get clusterrolebinding onboarding -o yaml`?

This might be a version mismatch since you created a `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1 ClusterRole` and `kubectl create clusterrole` will create a `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1 ClusterRoleBinding`.

You should upgrade your `ClusterRole` to version `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1`.

Comment: Both were created with the more current version: https://gist.github.com/dwatrous/62c2ead8282e4adc4198304356f6dbb1